# How to get index of elements of string array?

Tags: collections, java-8, java-stream

I have the below data in a `String[] strArray`

> 1, 9, 3, 4, 16, 6, 7, 8, 2, 10, 11, 12, 13, 45

I want to find the index of those elements that contain `3` (e.g:3,13). i.e I should have 3=str[2] and 13=str[12] with just use ****Java 8** features** like stream and etc. because I want after finding their index, to replace them with specific string for example `"Test"`

Comment: Can you please share your attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way. Use the ternary operator `(?:)` to decide if the current string should be replaced with `Test` or the original value.

```
String[] vals = { "1", "9", "3", "4", "16", "6", "7", "8",
        "2", "10", "11", "12", "13", "45" };

vals = Arrays.stream(vals)
        .map(str -> str.contains("3") ? "Test" : str)
        .toArray(String[]::new);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(vals));
```

prints

```
[1, 9, Test, 4, 16, 6, 7, 8, 2, 10, 11, 12, Test, 45]
```

To return a map of array element to index for the found matches you can do it like so. This will handle duplicate values with different indices.

- Stream the indices of the array
- filter the indices for values that match
- convert the index to an Integer (via boxed - required for collector) using grouping by.
- then assign to map using the filtered indices. The value is a list of where each instance of the `key` was found.

```
String[] vals = { "1", "9", "3", "4", "16", "6", "7", "8",
        "2", "10", "11", "12", "13", "45", "43", "3", "13" };

Map<String, List<Integer>> results = IntStream.range(0,vals.length)
        .filter(i -> vals[i].contains("3"))
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i->vals[i]));
 
results.forEach((k,v)-> System.out.println(k + " -> " + v));
```

prints

```
13 -> [12, 16]
3 -> [2, 15]
43 -> [14]
```

To replace the original array with the indices of its values in the map, do the following.

```
for (String key : results.keySet()) {
    for (int i : results.get(key)) {
        vals[i] = i+"";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but actually I want to have an index of element in the original array, i.e. i need know which element index of String[] val was "3" then I store element address for example val[2] was "3"

Comment: So do you just want an array of indices?  LIke `int[]{2, 12}`.  Can you show the expected output?

Comment: dear @WJS it would be better to have map, i want to know which indexes of array are 3,5,15 ,i.e:
String[] val = {1,2,3,4,5,3,..,9,5,15}
i should have: map: indexes={"key3","index2";"key5":"index4";..."key15":"index14"}

Comment: I updated my answer.  I presume you wanted the actual value and index and not the prefixed strings of "key" and "index" (but that would be easy to add).

Comment: I thought that there could be duplicate values in the array so I modified my answer to support that.

Comment: Thanks, dear, can you tell me what I should do just replace String[] val with int[] val, i.e. my original data are in int array according to your solution I want add some logic such as check val[i] % 3 == 0 then replac correspond index from String val with "Test" , I think we can do this also: for example int[] val={1,2,...,15} if val[I] % 3 == 0 then string array val[i]="Test" , could i explani my orginal need clearly?

Comment: I went ahead and updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can take the length of the array and iterate from i=0 to i<length. In the loop convert str[i] to a String and check if that string contains “3” using the Java String Contains() method, if so you can replace at that spot in the array str[i]=“Test”

Alternatively you can do the same thing using the Java Stream method, Map.

```
str.stream().map(x-> {if(String.valueOf(x).contains(“3”)) return “Test”;}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You may want to use .toArray rather than collect as a list in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your response but actually I want to have an index of element in the original array, i.e. i need know which element index of String[] val was "3" then I store element address for example val[2] was "3"